# Why the if chain doesn't start in this code?

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a programm that prints the day after the date it reads.
I can't understand why when the programm runs on terminal it ends when it prints on display "Date is %d/%d/%d\n" and the if chain doesn't start in the programm.
I tried to insert a printf after every single if to see if it works but, since it stops before, I can't also see if there some logical, or grammatical, problem and I can't do debug.
So I'm sorry in advance if there we'll be some logical mistake after the first if, but I can't see it on terminal!
Can anyone explain me why I have this problem?
Thank you in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
int d, m, y, days;
double leap;
printf("Insert day: \n");
scanf("%d", &d);
printf("Insert month: \n");
scanf("%d", &m);
printf("Insert year: \n");
scanf("%d", &y);
printf("Date is %d/%d/%d\n", d, m, y);

if  (m==1 || m==3 || m==5 || m==7 || m==8 || m==10) {
    days==31;
    if  (d<days) {
        d=d+1;
        printf("The next day is %d/%d/%d!\n", d, m, y);
    }
    else if (d==days) {
        d==1;
        m=m+1;
        printf("The next day is %d/%d/%d!\n", d, m, y);
    }
}
else if (m==12) {
    days==31;
    if  (d<days) {
        d=d+1;
        printf("The next day is %d/%d/%d!\n", d, m, y);
    }
    else if (d==days) {
        d==1;
        m==1;
        y=y+1;
        printf("The next day is %d/%d/%d!\n", d, m, y);
    }
}
else if (m==4 || m==6 || m==9 || m==11) {
    days==30;
    if (d<days) {
        d=d+1;
        printf("The next day is %d/%d/%d!\n", d, m, y);
    }
    else if (d==days) {
        m=m+1;
        printf("The next day is %d/%d/%d!\n", d, m, y);
    }
}
else if (m==2) {
    leap=(y)%(4);
    if  (leap==0) {
        days==29;
        if (d==days) {
            d==1;
            m=m+1;
            printf("The next day is %d/%d/%d!\n", d, m, y);
        }
        else if (d<days) {
            d=d+1;
            printf("The next day is %d/%d/%d!\n", d, m, y);
        }
        else {
            days==28;

            if (d==days) {
                d==1;
                m=m+1;
                printf("The next day is %d/%d/%d!\n", d, m, y);
            }
            else if (d==days) {
                d=d+1;
                printf("The next day is %d/%d/%d!\n", d, m, y);
            }
        }
    }
}
else if (m>12) {
    printf ("The date doesn't exist!\n");
}
```

}

Comment: Start from proper indentation. It is *very* helpful when dealing with nested statements. Looking at your code it is very difficult to tell which `else` belongs to which `if`

Comment: @Sergio Imperiale Show the values you entered.

Comment: You're using `==` (checking equality) in a number of places where you meant to use `=` (assignment).

Comment: You can use a site like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_c_formatter.htm to indent the code automatically for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C the operator `==` is used for comparison, not assignment. Therefor change `==` to `=` in the intended assignments.

When you compile a C program you should always enable warnings and read them carefully. For example, with the GCC compiler and the option `-Wall` you will see warnings like

```
warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
days == 30;
```

Comment: Thank you, maybe my mistake was in the indentation, because it was too confusing and I did this mistake. Now, changing == with = everything works perfectly.
Thank you again!